# Filter dataframe based on multiple columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID1    ID2
0   foo    bar
1   fizz   buzz
```

And another like this:

```
    ID1    ID2    Count    Code   
0   abc    def      1        A
1   fizz   buzz     5        A
2   fizz1  buzz2    3        C
3   foo    bar      6        Z
4   foo    bar      6        Z
```

What I would like to do is filter the second dataframe where ID1 and ID2 match a row in the first dataframe, and whenever there's a match I want to remove that row from the first dataframe to avoid duplicates.  This would yield a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID1    ID2    Count    Code   
1   fizz   buzz     5        A
3   foo    bar      6        Z
```

I know I can do this by nesting for loops, stepping through all the rows, and manually removing a row from the first frame whenever I get a match but I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this.  I am not experienced in pandas so there may be a much cleaner way to do that I do not know about.  I was previously using `.isin()` but had to scrap it.  Each ID pair can exist in the dataframe up to N times and I need the filtered frame to contain between 0 and N instances of a pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), if only same columns for join in both `df`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2.drop_duplicates())
print (df)
    ID1   ID2  Count Code
0   foo   bar      6    Z
1  fizz  buzz      5    A
```

If need check dupes only in `ID` columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID1','ID2']))
print (df)
    ID1   ID2  Count Code
0   foo   bar      6    Z
1  fizz  buzz      5    A
```

If more columns are overlaping add parameter `on`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['ID1','ID2'])
```

---

If not remove dupe rows:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2)
print (df)
    ID1   ID2  Count Code
0   foo   bar      6    Z
1   foo   bar      6    Z
2  fizz  buzz      5    A
```

Comment: Sorry I get different number of entries comparing with your method with `df1.loc[(df1.ID1.isin(df1.ID1))&(df1.ID2.isin(df2.ID2)),:].drop_duplicates()` with my real data. Just wonder why this issue happens?

Comment: @ahbon - yes, I think I know. Problem is if use double isin it testing each column separately, not pairs `ID1`, `ID2`

Comment: Understand, so your solution is more what I need to use. Anyway is it possible to use `isin` to realize same method as `merge` as in your solutions for pairs `ID1, ID2`?

Comment: @ahbon - theoretically yes, if create tuples of `ID1`, `ID2` for both DataFrames and then compare by `isin`, but it is slow, beter here is `merge`

Answer (score 4):

Using `isin` on a list of tuples

```
df2[
    pd.Series(
        list(zip(df2.ID1.values, df2.ID2.values))
    ).isin(list(zip(df1.ID1.values, df1.ID2.values)))
]

    ID1   ID2  Count Code
1  fizz  buzz      5    A
3   foo   bar      6    Z
4   foo   bar      6    Z
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df2.merge(df1[['ID1','ID2']])
```

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe try this ?

```
df.loc[(df.ID1.isin(df1.ID1))&(df.ID2.isin(df1.ID2)),:].drop_duplicates()


Out[224]: 
    ID1   ID2  Count Code
1  fizz  buzz      5    A
3   foo   bar      6    Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge was almost what I wanted, but didn't quite do the job because I have an odd set of requirements where I need to filter out some duplicates but not all the duplicates.  A regular merge doesn't work because that keeps all the duplicates and `drop_duplicates()` doesn't work because I need to allow some duplicates.  I ended up going with the method I described in the question and nested for loops.

```
temp_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns.df2.columns)
for i in xrange(len(df2)):
    for ii in xrange(len(df1)):
        if df2['ID1'].iloc[i] == df1['ID1'].iloc[ii] and df2['ID2'].iloc[i] == df1['ID2'].iloc[ii]:
            df1.drop(df1.index[ii], inplace=True)
            temp_frame = temp_frame.append(df2.iloc[i], ignore_index=True)
            break
df1 = temp_frame.copy()
```